# Using Blazor @bind in Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page app with forms. Because of necessity of using "dynamic" pictures I would like to use @bind feature from Blazor in the created Forms. I mean exactly as the @bind on the screenshot. Picture is taken from tutorial video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oeh2IJw7Zig&t=2353s]
[image]

Is it possible to add this functionality in Razor Pages Core App? Without "rewriting" all into Blazor webapp type.

Comment: If you don't have a live data stream, how is the page going to handle a 2-way bind?

Comment: So, it is impossible?

Comment: Razor Pages doesn't support live 2-way databinding. You need a client-side solution, like Blazor or Knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add this functionality in Razor Pages Core App?
> Without "rewriting" all into Blazor webapp type.

No. Only Blazor support `@bind`. No document said you can use `@bind` for ASP.NET Core plain Razor Pages.

Reference documents

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind